# fastboot hangs (but adb works)

Tags: usb, android

On a MacBook Air M1 running Big Sur, I have an Android device (Fairphone 4) connected with a USB-C cable (both ends are USB-C, there is no adapter or hub). I've enabled developer options, adb and OEM unlocking. I have `android-platform-tools` 34.0.0 installed through Homebrew. The `adb` command works fine. But `fastboot` doesn't. Even **`fastboot devices` just hangs**. The state of the device (running normally, or with fastboot running after doing `adb reboot bootloader`) doesn't matter. `sudo fastboot devices` doesn't help.

How can I make `fastboot` work on my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

What made it work for me was to plug the USB cable in a different port! Either port works for adb, but **fastboot seems to only work with the USB port that's furthest back**.

- If no USB device is plugged in, `fastboot devices` hangs.
- If a non-Android USB device is plugged in on any port, `fastboot devices` returns immediately.
- If the phone is connected to the USB-C port that's furthest from the back, fastboot doesn't detect it.
- If the phone is connected to the USB-C port that's closest to the back, fastboot detects it normally: `fastboot devices` returns immediately with no output if the device isn't in fastboot mode, and `fastboot devices` lists the device if the device is in fastboot mode. Fastboot commands work if the device is connected to the back USB port and in fastboot mode.